# Google Form Script - Optimize how the form reads the last response?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-forms

I have this script in a Google form:

```
function onSubmit()
{
  var response = FormApp.getActiveForm().getResponses()[FormApp.getActiveForm().getResponses().length - 1].getItemResponses()

  if (response[2].getResponse()[0] === 'Notify the community manager of a livestream report in real time?' && response[1].getItem().getTitle() === 'Page/Group Identification')
  {
        UrlFetchApp.fetch('https://discord.com/api/webhooks/824374930422497331/X', {headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/json'}, method: 'POST', payload: JSON.stringify({content: '<https://www.facebook.com/' + response[1].getResponse() + '>'})})
  }

    if (response[2].getResponse()[0] === 'Notify the community manager of a livestream report in real time?' && response[1].getItem().getTitle() === 'Channel Identification')
  {
    UrlFetchApp.fetch('https://discord.com/api/webhooks/824374930422497331/X', {headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/json'}, method: 'POST', payload: JSON.stringify({content: '<https://www.youtube.com/channel/' + response[1].getResponse() + '>'})})
  }

      if (response[2].getResponse()[0] === 'Notify the community manager of a livestream report in real time?' && response[1].getItem().getTitle() === 'Account Username')
  {
    UrlFetchApp.fetch('https://discord.com/api/webhooks/824374930422497331/X', {headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/json'}, method: 'POST', payload: JSON.stringify({content: '<https://www.tiktok.com/@' + response[1].getResponse() + '>'})})
  }
}
```

It works like a charm, but an issue has popped up after some months. After form submission, it takes 60-80 seconds before the webhook gets triggered. I think it is because the form spends a lot of time going through the 150,000 responses and finding the last one. When I created a copy of the form, the webhook was fired instantly upon form submission. Is there a way to optimize how the form reads the last response?

Comment: Please don't vandalize your posts. Part of the agreement when you post here is that Stack Exchange has the right to continue to distribute the content. This is especially true given that you already received an answer that evidently helped you, given that you accepted it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Forms has a built in message to find the form that triggered an event. See below to establish a method to be guaranteed to get latest response. Alternatively, consider the second approach to just go with latest -1.

```
/**
 * Executed when new entry received. This needs to be setup using EDIT --->  Current Project Triggers
 */
function entryMade(e) {
  reviewResponse_(e.response);
}
```

This should also work with minimal overhead:

```
function getLatestResponse() {
  var allResponses = FormApp.getActiveForm().getResponses();
  var latestResponse= allResponses[allResponses.length - 1];
  return latestResponse;
}
```